# FactoryGirl creates user, but save point is released before test starts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am running rspec tests for spec/requests/user_pages_specs:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "home page" do
    before { visit root_path }

    it { should have_content('Sign up with Facebook') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('')) }
  end

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user.id) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end
end
```

As you can see, I am using FactoryGirl to create a user. When I run the same command (i.e. `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`) is `rails console test --sandbox`, a user is properly created and saved.

When I run my tests however, FactoryGirl creates the user in the database, and then releases it before the test actually runs. I can see this from test.log:

```
[1m[36mActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"[0m
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36m (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSAVEPOINT active_record_1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Exists (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('test@foobar.com') LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mSQL (2.0ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "email", "name", "oauth_expires_at", "oauth_token", "provider", "uid", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)[0m  [["created_at", Wed, 23 Apr 2014 16:17:16 UTC +00:00], ["email", "test@foobar.com"], ["name", "Test User"], ["oauth_expires_at", Wed, 23 Apr 2014 00:00:00 UTC +00:00], ["oauth_token", "10987654321ABCDEFG"], ["provider", "facebook"], ["uid", "12345"], ["updated_at", Wed, 23 Apr 2014 16:17:16 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (0.0ms)[0m  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1
Started GET "/users/1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-04-23 10:17:16 -0600
Processing by UsersController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"id"=>"1"}
  [1m[36mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "1"]]
```

Why is this happening and how do I stop it from releasing until after the tests?

Comment: what do you mean by "releasing" the user... do your tests fail? if so - can you give us the error message? Id you've solved the problem in the meantime... can you add it as an "answer" so this question on longer shows up in the "unanswered" queue? :)

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you find any solution for this issue?